# Compounding Gamma with Gamma to yield F-distribution?

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, f-distribution, compound-distributions

I am working through some problems from my Bayesian Statistics course and am having trouble understanding a step in the solution to a question. For reference this is the question:

[image: gammadistquestion]

And here is the solution:

[image: gammaquesitonsol]

In particular I am having trouble understanding the step where the integral disappears and the multiple of the Gamma functions becomes the beta function. I am aware of the relation

$$
\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b) = \mathrm{B}(a,b)\Gamma(a+b)
$$
but I cannot see how this has been applied as there is no $\Gamma(a+b)$ term present. I am also unsure of how the integral has been evaluated and would appreciate any explanation or help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Work out the integration step between lines 4 and 5.

Comment: @Xi'an, apologies for not being clear but I had actually attempted to evaluate this integral and was unable to figure it out. Would you please be able to provide a hint as to how to go about doing so?

Comment: This is a regular Gamma integral, missing normalising constants, all you have to do it to identify the parameters of that Gamma.

Comment: @Xi'an ah I see, cheers! I've got it all worked out now. Is there any way for me to mark this question as answered or give you credit for the help?

Comment: Congrats! You can write your complete resolution as the answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @Xi'an I have figured out the step between lines 4 and 5 of the solution as follows:

Let
$$
u=z\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}\right),
$$
then we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}z} = \frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2} \implies \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}\right)}\mathrm{d}u,
$$
and also
$$
z=\frac{u}{\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}\right)},
$$
which allows us to write the integral in line 4 as
$$
\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}\right)^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}\int\limits_0^{\infty} u^{\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u,
$$
which by the Gamma integral is equal to
$$
\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}\right)^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\right),
$$
and the rest of the solution follows.

Thanks again for your assistance @Xi'an.